# Extract URL from a server in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a Node.js server and I need to extract one part from a URL with this structure:

```
https://lets-talk-saku-gie-sakura.c9users.io/sala?extract
```

I just need the `extract` part.

I need to use the app.get method. However, the only way that I've found is:

```
app.get('/sala/:id', function (req, res) {
    req.params.id;
});
```

This doesn't work; do you know how can I extract it?

Answer (score 0):

`req.params` is for URL parameters like `:id`. Since you want a query parameter you should use `req.query` instead.

```
app.get('/sala/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
});
```

Comment: but the Url doesn't contain "=", I need what there is after "?"

Comment: Just look at the keys in `req.query`

Answer (score 0):

`req.query` might seem like a way to do this but, unfortunately, it's only useful when you know or expect certain query strings. Your best bet, I think, is to use `req.originalUrl` and then use a regular expression to find the part of the url you want to extract. See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl

Answer (score 0):

The nodejs [HTTP doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) has an example that can help you:

```
var obj = require('url').parse(req.url);
console.log(obj.query); // output: extract
```